# using of above as prep and after veb to be

Tags: grammar

is the using of above always prep?

I mean the word above goes with and should be using only with verb to be?

The sky is above the cloud.

Comment: *The plane **flies above** the ground, The water **lays above** the ground, Calmer heads **stay above** the fray,...*

Comment: Thanks..that mean we can use (above) as prep with present and all tenses.

Answer (score 0):

"Above" is a preposition, but it doesn't always have to follow a form of "to be".  For example:

- We looked at the canyon from the overlook above the river.
- The bird flew above the trees.
- Chicken must be cooked to an internal temperature above 170 degrees.